# Using a data frame as a look up table for a list

Tags: r, list, lookup-tables

having a R-list of "item keys" and one data frame of unique key-value pairs of "item keys" and corresponding "item names", I would like to add these "item names" in another list, corresponding to the original list of item keys. Please look at the sample code below to get a better idea of what I ask for. Any suggestions?

```
# step 1: make the data fram of "item keys" and corresponding "item names"
Keys <- c("5763", "5832", "5767", "5768")
Names <- c("sugar", "milk", "coffee", "tea")
KeyNames <- data.frame(Keys, Names)

# step 2: make a list of items. Each list entry has a variable number of items. 
ItemsList_Keys  <- replicate(10, 
    sample(Keys, size = sample(1:5, size = 1, replace = T), 
    replace=T), simplify = F)

# Have a look at the ItemsList..
 print(ItemsList_Keys[1:2])
[[1]]
[1] "5767" "5768" "5763" "5767"

[[2]]
[1] "5832" "5763" "5832" "5768" "5763"

# step 3:
# then I would like to make a "ItemsList_Names", 
# similar to "ItemsList_Keys", but prividing the "Names" 
# corresponding to the "Keys".. 


ItemsList_Names <- # .. something ..


# .. that would result in a list as shown below:    
ItemsList_Names[1]
[[1]]
[1] "coffee" "tea" "sugar" "coffee"
```

Comment: Try `lapply(ItemsList_Keys, function(x) KeyNames$Names[match(x, KeyNames$Keys)])`.

Comment: Yess thank you, exactly what I was looking for:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I like to use named vectors for this.

In your case you just need to use your `Keys` as names for your `Names`

```
names (Names) <- Keys
lapply (ItemsList_Keys, function (x) Names[x])
```

Be careful to convert to character your`Keys` vector if it was numeric.

Comment: Not totally the expected output because of the column names.

Comment: Hi Pascal. I am not sure to understand your comment. If the list ItemsList_Keys has names (as if it was a data.frame) then lapply will keep them.

Comment: I speak about the output only. As you can see when you apply your code, it adds column names to each vector. At the moment, it is not totally the OP's expected output. But if OP doesn't mind, it is good way to perform replacements.

Comment: True :)  I t keeps _Keys_ as the names of the vectors in the list. Usually I like it... but depends on what are you up to.

Comment: Oh, personally, I really don't care ^_^. Just wondering from OP viewpoint.

Comment: Yes this was a clever approach! Just had to recall the "unname()" function;-)

Comment: Yes but you will have to use it in a second lapply to get a result similar to that of Pascal.